# SSL Connection from Java Client using self-signed cert

Tags: java, client, self-signed

I need to use self-signed trusted certificate but having problems making connection from java client.

I have trust store set-up with the self-signed cert/pw.

Where I am having the issue is how to incorporate the wsse security header into the java web service call. I am told I need to include this self-signed cert in the soap payload after the ssl connection is established.

I am setting up the ConfigurationContext as follows...How do I include the security header in the actual web service call...Please advise...thanks jim

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "c:\\cvp.keystore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "changeit");



ConfigurationContext ctx = getConfigurationContext(getMaxOutgoingConnections(appDir, getHostName(), LOBSB_TYPE));
String epLoc = getEndpointLocation(appDir, getHostName(), SERVICE_TYPE);
ListParticipantExport4_ListParticipantHttpServiceStub stub = new ListParticipantExport4_ListParticipantHttpServiceStub(ctx,epLoc);

/*
if (!setSecurityOptions(stub._getServiceClient())) {
    throw new Exception("Error setting up security options!");
}
*/


int timeOut = getTimeout(appDir, getHostName(), SERVICE_TYPE);
if (timeOut > 0) {
    //Only set the timeout value if greater
    //than zero!
            stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setTimeOutInMilliSeconds(timeOut);
        }

ListParticipantDocument doc = ListParticipantDocument.Factory.newInstance();
ListParticipant part = ListParticipant.Factory.newInstance();
ListParticipantRequest req = ListParticipantRequest.Factory.newInstance();

ServiceAttributesType saType = ServiceAttributesType.Factory.newInstance();
saType.setApplicationIdentifier("IVR");
saType.setLogLevel(ServiceAttributesType.LogLevel.ERRORS);
saType.setVersion("1.0");
req.setServiceAttributes(saType);

ParticipantSelection partSel = ParticipantSelection.Factory.newInstance();
partSel.setAccountHolderSSN(accountHolderSSN);
req.setParticipantSelection(partSel);

part.setListParticipantRequest(req);
doc.setListParticipant(part);

long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
sharedlib.listparticipant_v3.ListParticipantResponseDocument respDoc = stub.listParticipant(doc);
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
respTime = (endTime-startTime);

ResponseReturnStatusType retStatus = respDoc.getListParticipantResponse().getListParticipantResponse().getResponseReturnStatus();
returnCode = retStatus.getResponseReturnCode().getCode();
returnCodeName = retStatus.getResponseReturnCode().getCodeName();
```